# navigationByUrl with variable angular

Tags: angular, navigation

I am working on a project which uses angular 8. In navigation, I have to add a navigation tab which go to another page using click event like below.

```html
(click)="this.router.navigateByUrl('[/,{this.store.Product$.getValue().Name},/product/list]');"
```

I am getting error in this above code. Is it possible to give the navigation like that? If not can any one  please suggest any alternate way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using template literals to form the URL

`` (click)="this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${this.store.Product$.getValue().Name}/product/list`)" ``

Comment: @sarasmare what url does it produce? Try logging the result of `/${this.store.Product$.getValue().Name}/product/list`.

Comment: {this.store.Product$.getValue().Name} i am getting value for this

Comment: Okay it is returning a value? @sarasm. Okay then try to use it to form your url